# Render multitype link field via fluid - TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

What is the best way to render [link field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufpiJ.jpg) in TYPO3 fluid template?

Link field is defined via flexform as:

```
<field_link type="array">
  <TCEforms type="array">
    <config type="array">
      <type>input</type>
      <eval>trim</eval>
      <wizards type="array">
        <link type="array">
        <type>popup</type>
        <title>Link</title>
        <icon>link_popup.gif</icon>
        <script>
          browse_links.php ? mode = wizard & amp;
          act = page
        </script>
        <params type="array">
          <blindLinkOptions>file,spec,email,folder</blindLinkOptions>
        </params>
        <JSopenParams>height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1</JSopenParams>
        </link>
      </wizards>
    </config>
    <label>link</label>
  </TCEforms>
</field_link>
```

Fluid comes with viewhelpers such as link.email, link.external, link.page but my link field could be either page id or external link or email or link to sys_file record. How do you handle that in your projects without making multiple if statemens in fluid template? (custom viewhelper?, typoscript object)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `f:link.page` to generate links external urls or files, that does not matter as internally `typolink` is used.

If you are using the wizards like in your example, you should use the `f:link.typolink` viewhelper which supports all attributes.

Comment: Thank you. The website is still running on TYPO3 6.2 and as I can see link.typolink is not part of the core in that version (it is part of the core in 7.x). Anyway thank you - I will backport this viewhelper to my installation.

Comment: But even I will use link.typolink - it does not help me - I still need to make multiple evaluations in fluid template.

Comment: Example in case of uid to page

<f:link.typolink parameter="{link}">
  Linktext
 </f:link.typolink>

and in case of email

<f:link.typolink parameter="mailto:{link}">
  Linktext
 </f:link.typolink>

and for sys_file it would be also different. So as I can see I should create own viewhelper so I will be able to put create different link types without making multiple if statements in fluid.

Comment: for me <f:link.typolink parameter="{link}"> for email works perfect. -> see my answer

Comment: Yes, that works fine in TYPO3 7, my website is still 6.2 so I need to backport this typolink viewhelper into 6.2 or upgrade to 7.

Answer (score 0):

Link for email works perfect

here my flexform:

```
<settings.link>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>Link</label>
        <config>
            <type>input</type>
            <size>30</size>
            <eval>trim</eval>
            <softref>typolink,typolink_tag,images,url</softref>
            <wizards>
                <_PADDING>2</_PADDING>
                <link>
                    <type>popup</type>
                    <title>Link</title>
                    <module>
                        <name>wizard_element_browser</name>
                        <urlParameters>
                            <mode>wizard</mode>
                        </urlParameters>
                    </module>
                    <icon>link_popup.gif</icon>
                    <script>browse_links.php?mode=wizard</script>
                    <params>
                        <blindLinkOptions>file,folder,url,spec</blindLinkOptions>
                    </params>
                    <JSopenParams>height=500,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1</JSopenParams>
                </link>
            </wizards>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.link>
```

Output:

```
<a href="javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto('nbjmup+nbjmAuzqpmjol\/dpn');">Liunk</a>
```